# Can't pass dynamically data from ajax to fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

I am sending a `select` value from the form. I receive an array with data from the Laravel controller. I am trying to pass this data to FullCalendar.

Every time I change the `select` I want to render the FullCalendar with the received data again.

I receive it from AJAX but when I pass the data to FullCalendar
`hiddenDays = serviceRange(data.hiddenDays[0]);`, it removes the wrong days or does not remove anything.

```js
const calendarEl = document.getElementById("calendar");

function ajaxCallback(callback) {
  $("select#select-service").change(function() {
    let ajaxResult = null;
    $.ajax({
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        method: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: getFreeDay + $(this).val(),
        data: {
          "id": $(this).val()
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
          $(".calendary-loader").css('display', 'block');
        },
      }).done(function(data) {
        callback(data);
        $(".calendary-loader").css('display', 'none');
      }).fail(function(data) {
        console.log($(this).data('id'))
        console.log(data.responseJSON.message);
      });
  });
}

let hiddenDays;
ajaxCallback(function(data) {
  hiddenDays = serviceRange(data.hiddenDays[0]);
  let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    locale: plLocale,
    plugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin, interactionPlugin, momentPlugin],
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next',
      center: 'title',
      right: ''
    },
    editable: true,
    hiddenDays: hiddenDays,
    selectable: true,
    selectAllow: function(select) {
      return moment().diff(select.start, 'days') <= 0
    }
  });
  
  calendar.destroy();
  calendar.render();
});

function serviceRange(data) {
  const week = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  const days = Object.values(data);
  const start = days[0];
  const end = days[1];
  const rangeAllowDays = [];
  for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    rangeAllowDays.push(i);
  }
  hiddenDays = week.filter(x => !rangeAllowDays.includes(x));
  return hiddenDays;
}
```

Controller:

```
public function getFreeDay(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {

        /* Range of services days */

        //disable these days for reservation, because of busy
        $hiddenDays = $this->serviceRangeOfDays($request->id)->toArray();
        
        //here will be other data, this is for test
        try {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'success',
                'hiddenDays' => $hiddenDays,
                'availableDays' =>['2022-02-25','2022-02-26'], //example data
                'availableHours' => ['08:30', '13:30'], //example data
                'id' => $request->id,
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'Wystąpił Błąd'
            ])->setStatusCode(500);
        }
    }
```

And AJAX returning:

```
{"status":"success","hiddenDays":[{"service_day_of_week_start":1,"service_day_of_week_end":5}],"availableDays":["2022-02-25","2022-02-26"],"availableHours":["08:30","13:30"],"id":"1"}
```

EDIT: change array range, because sunday is 0, not 7.
const week = [0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

Comment: Suggestion: don't re-render the whole calendar every time you receive new data. Use fullCalendar's `setOption` method to just change the specific setting you're interested in. Also you really don't need `success: callback,` if you've got `.done`...otherwise you're duplicating calls to the callback (one of which will likely do the wrong thing due to the lack of input data going into it). Also `data: callback(data);` doesn't make much sense. What's the `data: ` bit for there? Just `callback(data);` is sufficient.

Comment: `it removes the wrong days or does not remove anything`... we can't see what data you're supplying, or what you expected to happen from the data you're supplying. We need to see the content of the data you're returning from the AJAX call in order to understand how it would be processed and what would finally get passed to fullCalendar.

Comment: @ADyson  I added a controller and a return from Ajax

Comment: And what result do you get with that data? What result did you expect instead? As far as I can see, it will hide all the days except Sunday, because your serviceRange function will return an array like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`. Is that what you expected? or did you want to hide all the days? Remember (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/hiddenDays) the numbers of the days are zero-based, so Sunday is 0, not 7. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/podKvaL

Comment: P.S. If you _do_ tell it to hide all the days, fullCalendar will throw an error and won't load - demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/oNoygyN . I think that makes sense, because if you try to hide everything, there's no way to display the calendar.

Comment: @ADyson yes, I return wrong array, using 7 over 0 :)

my week array should start from 0 to 6... :)

Comment: Ok. But as I say above, if you try to hide all the days you will crash the calendar anyway.

Comment: I'm just return days which are hidden like (0,6) sunday saturday. 
I pass to function serviceRange  start day and end day (1 monday, 5 friday) and return only hidden days (0,6)

Comment: I see. I think your serviceRange function needs some work, then.

Comment: @ADyson yes thank you. What would you recommend to dynamically arrange events? For example, I will get data with Ajax json with the date and name of the event and would like to dynamically assign it to the date. I don't see such a possibility in setOption

Comment: I think that's a separate question to what you asked above? You're correct you don't set events with setOption (I suggested that as a way to change the hiddenDays option without re-rendering everything). The normal way to provide events to the calendar is to configure a data source with one of the event feed options - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source